# Как сделать "жесткое соединение" используя b2RevoluteJointDef?

Tags: box2d

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь сделать жесткое соединение используя b2RevoluteJointDef и ограничив угол, т.к. в box2d v2.2.1 нет CreateFixture2. Не получается создать именно жесткое соединение. Вот код:

```
b2RevoluteJointDef jointDef12;//создаем определение соединения
            jointDef12.bodyA = bodyM; //первое тело соединения
            jointDef12.bodyB = bodyM2; //второе тело соединения
            jointDef12.collideConnected = false; //тела не сталкиваются
            jointDef12.localAnchorA = b2Vec2(-2, -8); //якорная точка первого тела
            jointDef12.localAnchorB = b2Vec2(6,-4); //якорная точка второго тела
            jointDef12.enableLimit = true; //включаем пределы
            jointDef12.upperAngle=0;
            jointDef12.referenceAngle = 0; //начальный угол соединения
            world.CreateJoint(&jointDef12); //добавляем соединение в мир
Вопрос, а почему соединенные тела при столкновениях о др. тела колеблются относительно друг друга(Ведь соединение жесткое)???
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Колебания и вообще не слишком корректное поведение соединенных тел - это проблема солверов практически всех современных физических движков, так как точно соблюсти все ограничения(создаваемые разными видами джойнтов, другими телами и т.д.) в общем случае нельзя.
Даже коммерческие продукты вроде знаменитого Havok страдают такой проблемой, и в играх типа Half-Life 2(особенно - Garry's mod, физическая песочница, мод к оригинальной игре) это очень заметно.

Прошу прощения, не помню какой версией B2D пользуюсь я, но уверен что возможность задать много шейпов одному телу должна быть. Сейчас заглянул в trunk Box2D, b2Body определенно имеет метод CreateFixture.

Comment: Похоже Вы правы, все перепробовал, даже сварное соединение-все равно есть колебания...